# what is the difference betwwen normal and initial (css)

Tags: html, css

What is difference between normal and initial in this properties?
Don't both do the same thing?

**[1st example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp)**

```
<p class="a">This is a paragraph, normal.</p>
<p class="b">This is a paragraph, italic.</p>
<p class="c">This is a paragraph, oblique.</p>

p.a {
    font-style: normal;
}

p.b {
   font-style: italic;
}

p.c {
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

**[2nd example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)**

```
<p class="normal">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="light">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="thick">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="thicker">This is a paragraph.</p>

p.normal {
    font-weight: normal;
}

p.thick {
    font-weight: bold;
}

p.thicker {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`initial` is a value that can be given to **any** property to set it back to its default value.

`normal` happens to be the default value for those two properties.

Comment: Why would you ever require `initial`? I can't say I have seen it out there once... Do you know why?

Comment: No reason just asking!
Then normal=initial?

Comment: "for those two properties"

Comment: Okay mate :D and here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp
auto=initial.....right?

Comment: @David: You only really need to use "initial" for CSS-wide properties such as the aptly named "all". Other than that, if you prefer hardcoding the initial value, there are no downsides to doing so.